# Retrieving a number in the form of a string from sqlite and casting to int

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 to store data for an app. An approximation of the code is as follows:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){

    char temp[50];
    int temp_int;

    strcpy(temp, argv[1]); //this works, strcpying from a string to a string 
    temp_int = argv[2]; // this yields an unexpected number

}

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlRetreive, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
```

I believe this is as expected since the call to sqlite is pulling everything as a string (I believe). I have tried casting it with (int) as in temp_int = (int) argv[2]; but that yields a slightly different unexpected number.

Is there anyway to pull specific columns as integers? or a way to cast this to receive the int we originally stored?c

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi

Comment: That did it - thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you cant directly assign a string as an integer even with recasting.  use instead the `<stdlib.h>` library function "`strtol()`"

```
#include <stdlib.h>

long temp_int;
char *ptr;     // temporary pointer

temp_int = strtol(argv[2], &ptr, 10);   // the '10' here means base-10

if (ptr == argv[2])  // no valid numeric was found to convert
{ 
    // failure occurred, string was not a base 10 numeric
    // so, handle appropriately
}

// otherwise, your temp_int now has the converted value
```

check the documentation for strtol().   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

strtol()  should always be used instead of atoi().   strtol() shows success if the &ptr is moved to the end of the converted string.   atoi() doesn't provide any possibility for error checking, and indicates an inexperienced programmer.